# Bamboo CLI: How do you add/clone a job?

Tags: bamboo

I've been using the bamboo cli to try and automate the create of new build projects/plans. However I've run into a snag that while you can clone projects/plans and add tasks to jobs, there seems to be no way to create/clone jobs.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to go to `Plan Configuration` on the left side menu and then select the tab `Stages`. There you can create a job.

Comment: Tx for your response. I want to do this using the cli, not using the gui.